# how to setup a node for a coin with only genesis block released

Tags: windows, bitcoin, bitcoind

I was working on a litecoin source where i modified it to generate a new genesis block. It went all good. I started the client. Now I have a problem that since its a new coin, the wallet keeps saying 1 hour behind from network, and no block source available, because its new genesis block, and has nothing to do with litecoin's blocks.

the question is how do I setup a node? Since this is the pc where I created the genesis block. I thought it would keep itself connected and sync new blocks. (Even though there are no miners on network, it should still sync).

I even added daemon=1 and then run the wallet on 2 different PCs. And I still couldn't sync.

I might be wrong here. How exactly do you people sync a new coin or setup a node?
I appreciate your help. Keep in mind all of the process done here by me is to understand how the cryptocurrency works.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to separate your network from Litecoin by using a new port number and pchMessageStart. You will also need to change the checkpoints so that it doesn't conflict with Litecoin.

You will need mining to sync. You need blocks to be able to sync to start with. Syncing can also get stuck until a new block comes through, and I think Litecoin still has this bug. So to keep a network syncing, blocks have to come through.